# When timer ends replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to make sure that when my timer ends I get a message intead of a form input. Everything works fine. I just need to write functioning if statement. This is my code:

```
var inputDate = new Date($('#count').val());
inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate());

$(".clock").countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek'));
    if (inputDate.val() == 0) {
        var statusHTML = '<p>Siūlymai nebegalimi. Aukciono laikas baigėsi.</p>';
        $("#placeBid").replaceWith(statusHTML);
    }
});
```

When my timer ends the message doesn't appear and the form still shows. If I do this:

```
if ($(".clock").val() == 0)
```

then the message appears but when timer is not ended it still shows the message instead of input.

**EDIT HTML CODE**

```
        <form id="placeBid" action="/add-new-bid/{{$product->id}}" method="Post">

        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <input type="submit" id="bidSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="Siūlyti kainą" style="float: right" />

        <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$product->bid_price}}" id="jsBidPrice">

            <input style="width: 144px;" type="number" name="bid" class="minBid form-control" min="{{$product->bid_price}}" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0.01, 100)" placeholder="min. suma {{$product->bid_price}} €" style="width: 100%;" />

        </div>​
        </form>
```

Comment: I don't know why would u vote this down :)

Comment: can you show html code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

```
Events
```

This plugin will trigger an event whenever some state change like:

```
Update: Triggered to update the DOM
Finish: Triggered when finished
Stop: Triggered that paused
```

To register a callback use the following event.type:

```
update.countdown
finish.countdown
stop.countdown
```

Be aware that ALL events should be registered with the namespace *.countdown.

Use finish event to get what you need?

btw. you have plenty of inforimations here:
[enter link description here](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#events)

Working example:

```
$('#clock').countdown('2016/03/04 13:01:00')
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) { 
**do all your shinigamis here**
});
```

Comment: Not working. I even added this date: `2016/03/03 00:01:00`

Comment: Fixed. I needed .clock not #clock :)

Comment: The above code is fine i tested it before adding. Copy/Paste one of the examples from documentation and check where are you doing smth. Wrong. Btw. Try to catch your element by ID not class.